# Question about linear systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Let $X=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ be a set of variables in $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $S_1$ be a set of linear equations of the form $a_1 x_1+\cdots+a_n x_n=b$ that are independent.
Let $k_1=|S_1|<n$ where $|S_1|$ denotes the rank of $S_1$ (i.e., the number of independent equations). 
That is, $S_1$ does not contain enough equations to uniquely specify the values of the variables in $X$.
How many other equations are needed to solve the system uniquely? The answer is $n - k_1$.

Let $M$ be a set of $n-k_1$ equations such that $S_1 \cup M$ is full rank (i.e., the system $S_1 \cup M$ can be solved uniquely). My first question is that how can one find a set $M$?

Let $S_2$ be a set of independent equations such that $|S_2|<n$ too. Now I want to find an $M$ such that both $S_1 \cup M$ and $S_2 \cup M$ are uniquely solvable. How can I find such an $M$? Note that $|M|$ must be $\ge \max(n-k_1,n-k_2)$.

What if we extend the question to $S_1,\cdots,S_m$ such that $S_1\cup M,\cdots,S_m\cup M$ are all uniquely solvable?

A partial answer is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reasonably easy algorithm if you already know some basic stuff about matrices:

Look at the coefficients matrix's rows as vectors in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ :

$$A:=\{ v_1=(a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n})\;,\;v_2=(a_{21},\ldots,a_{2n})\,\ldots,v_k=(a_{k1},\ldots,a_{kn})\}\;\;(\text{where $\,k=k_1\;$ for simplicity of notation)}$$

Since you're given the equations are independent that means $\,A\,$ is a linearly independent set of vectors in $\,\Bbb R^n\;$ .

Well, now just "simply" complete the set $\,A\,$ to a basis of $\,\Bbb R^n\,$ and that's all...you can do this by taking the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\a_{k1}&a_{k2}&\ldots&a_{kn}\end{pmatrix}$$

and adding each time a new row $\,(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\,$ . Check whether this matrix is singular or not (for example, reducing this matrix and checking the row you added doesn't become all zeros!), and continue on until you get an $\,n\times n\$ regular matrix and voila!

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio. "**adding a new row ...**", how do we choose a new row? Randomly? or you have a better idea? If it is chosen randomly, how do you extend your algorithm to more than one $S_i$?

Comment: If you have the actual vectors $\,v_1,...,v_k\,$ then simple inspection sometimes can be helpful to have an "educated guess" about what possible vector can we add. In general, though, it's not hard to prove that we can *always* add elements from a given, fixed basis, so you can *always* choose your vectors from the standard basis. This shall make things considerably easier. And the algorithm is: add first vector, then add another, then...etc. Of course, you can try to add two or more vectors simultaneously and then throw away the ones where we'll get a row of zeros and keep the other ones...

Comment: Your algorithm is a actually a brute-force search for the answer which is quite inefficient. Consider this example: Assume we only use 0/1 coefficients and assume $S_i$ contains $n-1$ equations such that all of the variables except $x_i$ can be computed. There are exponentially many answers but only $M=\{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=b\}$ is the correct one. So, brute-force searching is not efficient and as you mentioned, I think we need an "educated guess".